# How to compare the contents of two hashes

Tags: perl, hash

I have two automatically-generated hashes which have the same number of elements, but I don't know how many.

I need to compare the second hash values with the first.

```
{
  TAP1 => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 1300, 2963, 3031, 16699, 16711, 36, 6634, 6837, 7233, 1103],
  TAP2 => [0, 0, 3291, 71, 2994, 6769, 10985],
  TAP3 => [0, 2795, 16395],
}
```

```
{
  TAP1 => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 130, 296, 3031, 16699, 1711, 3, 664, 6837, 723, 113],
  TAP2 => [0, 0, 3291, 75, 295, 6778, 10985],
  TAP3 => [0, 273, 16394],
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: @ikegami I need to compare the values of each  version of keys then create a new hash. If there is any change in the second version, store the new value in the new hash. If the value of the first version is same as the second version, store the same value. Is it bit confusing?

Comment: @nandeeshv: It sounds like you just want a copy of the second hash? Or are you talking about each element of the arrays?

Comment: @Borodin. It's just an example. Sometimes the second hash values might or might not change. So, I need to store the changed one. But if there's no change I retain the same previous value.

Comment: If there's a change, you want to use the new value. If there's no change, you want to retaining the previous value, which is the same as using the new value. So you want to use the new value no matter what. According to what you said, you simply want a use the second hash.

Comment: @ikegami. Oh sorry for my naive way of thinking. Yes you are right, I have realized that I can discard the first one. Thanks a lot for reminding.

Comment: @nandeeshv: So you don't even need to compare them! But at least you now know how.

Comment: @Borodin. You are absolutely right Borodin. I completely missed the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to know is whether they match or not, then you can use [`Data::Compare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Compare). The `Compare` function that it exports returns *true* if the structures match or *false* if they are different, which is the opposite of the Perl `cmp` and `<=>`

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Compare 'Compare';

my %taps1 = (
  TAP1 => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 1300, 2963, 3031, 16699, 16711, 36, 6634, 6837, 7233, 1103],
  TAP2 => [0, 0, 3291, 71, 2994, 6769, 10985],
  TAP3 => [0, 2795, 16395],
);

my %taps2 = (
  TAP1 => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 130, 296, 3031, 16699, 1711, 3, 664, 6837, 723, 113],
  TAP2 => [0, 0, 3291, 75, 295, 6778, 10985],
  TAP3 => [0, 273, 16394],
);


printf "The hashes are %s\n",
        Compare(\%taps1, \%taps2) ? 'identical' : 'different';

for my $key ( sort keys %taps1 ) {
    printf "The %s elements are %s\n",
            $key,
            Compare($taps1{$key}, $taps2{$key}) ? 'identical' : 'different';
}
```

#### output

```
The hashes are different
The TAP1 elements are different
The TAP2 elements are different
The TAP3 elements are different
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Borodin. Can I extend this one to multiple hashes like   Compare(\%taps1, \%taps2,\%taps3)

Comment: @nandeeshv: You must compare them two at a time. Think about it with scalars. `'a' eq 'a'` is fine, but what is `'a' eq 'a' eq 'b'` or `eq('a', 'a', 'b')`?